# Sequel pro won't connect anymore

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I'm running into some trouble right now. I worked yesterday on my db using sequel pro for TigerV1 (for an old OS X 10.4 powerpc). The problem is, this morning, sequel pro won't connect anymore. I deleted my "Favorite" and than retyped the host-user-password.

It's not letting me acces my db.

This is the error message : 
Unable to connect to host xxx.xxxxx.ca, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 30 seconds).

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'xx-xx.xx.xxxxxxx.ca' (using password: YES)

MySQL version did not change since yesterday, nor my version of sequel pro. Pleaze help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely some permissions are out of sync. Did you create this user or change any permissions yesterday? It's possible that the privilege tables were flushed in between yesterday and today, making whatever changes you made take effect.

Some possible issues:

1. The username/password has changed.
2. Remote connections have been disabled.
3. You don't have permission to access the DB you're trying to connect to.
4. MySQL has an IP or hostname whitelist which your IP or hostname is not on.

Some things to try:

1. Try connecting via the console if you have SSH access. If it lets you connect, check your user permissions really well. Be sure that remote connections are allowed and that you've whitelisted your IP address. Be sure to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` when you're done.
2. If you do not have SSH access, double check all the permissions in the control panel.
3. Try restarting MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

add your public ip in **remote mysql** every time when reconnected with internet or use static ip. it's just remote connection problem. 
use this link for more information about remote mysql - https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Remote+MySQL#